# Generating PDF using PHPExcel and DomPDF

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel, dompdf

I am trying to generate PDF from Excel file using PHPExcel and DomPDF. I tried all the examples and answers here but there is still a problem with my setPdfRenderer. coz the NOTICE text is showing when I run.

Here's the code so far.

```
function createPDF($filename){

//PHPExcel
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/export/'.$filename.'.xls';
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFile);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'dompdf';
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin/'.$rendererLibrary;

if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererLibrary,$rendererLibraryPath)){
    die(
        'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        '<br />' .
        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
    );
}

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('summaryOnLateReportSubmissions.php', 'export/' . $filename . '.pdf', __FILE__));
return true;
```

}